# C# - Storing struct(s) in setting file

Tags: c#, object, struct, setting

I only wanted to store some main configuration in a settings file, since the configuration may change any time.
The users of my application will be able to manage some stuff in several environments.
Each environment has its own configuration (Paths to network locations basicly).

I built an struct for each environment, but now we have to add some more environments, so it is helpful to store that configuration outside of the source code.

So, let me give you some code. I built two structs to describe each environment:

```
public struct env_conf
{
   string title;
   string path_to_xml;
   string path_to_sharepoint;
   List<subfolder> subfolders;
   //Some more strings

   public env_conf(string title, string path_to_xml, string path_to_sharepoint ...)
   {
     //Constructor which is setting the variables
   }
}

public struct subfolder
{
   string folder;
   bool is_standard;

   public env_conf(string folder, bool is_standard)
   {
     //Constructor which is setting the variables
   }
}
```

And this is how the environment configs are set up:

```
var finance_conf = new env_conf("MyTitle","MyXMLPath","MySPPath",
new List<subfolder>{new subfolder("MySubFolder",true);new subfolder("MySubFolder2",false)}
);

var sales_conf = new env_conf("MySalesTitle","MySalesXMLPath","MySalesSPPath",
new List<subfolder>{new subfolder("MySalesSubFolder",true);new subfolder("MySalesSubFolder2",false)}
);
```

This last step - the definition of the config-instances shall now be inside of a settings file.

Saving `string` and also `string[]` in settings file was no problem for me so far. But now I have more than that...

More than that, I do NOT have Visual Studio. I work with SharpDevelop, which was very good so far.

Marking my structs as serializable was not helpful. Also, when I manually set the type of the setting to `MyNamespace.env_conf`, it wont appear in the settings designer - only a "?" appears in the Type-field.
So for now, I don't know how to proceed. Also, all the info I find in the internet doesn't seem to help me. Please help me.

How has my XML settings file to be edited?
How has my source code to be edited?

Greetings!

Comment: Why are you using a struct instead of a class? And what's wrong with serialization?

Comment: Could also be a class, you're right. Since I only have variables and no functions in it, a struct will do the same.
Dont know why serialization won't work, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I also don't know why your serialization doesn't work - because *you don't describe what you do other than setting an attribute*.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by creating serializable classes, then you can deserialize the config file to an instance of your class, and you'll have all the settings.

For example, the classes might look like:

```
[Serializable]
public class EnvironmentConfig
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string XmlPath { get; set; }
    public string SharepointPath { get; set; }
    public List<SubFolder> SubFolders { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Title}: {XmlPath}, {SharepointPath}, {string.Join(", ", SubFolders.Select(s => s.Folder))}";
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SubFolder
{
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public bool IsStandard { get; set; }
}
```

And then in code, you can create an instance of your class, give it some values, and serialize it to a config file. Later, you can deserialize this file to load any changes your users may have made.

This example creates a default config and displays the values to the console. Then it gives the user a chance to modify the file, and displays the new values.

```
// Create a default config
var defaultEnvCfg = new EnvironmentConfig
{
    Title = "USWE Environment",
    XmlPath = @"\\server\share\xmlfiles",
    SharepointPath = @"\\server\sites\enterpriseportal\documents",

    SubFolders = new List<SubFolder>
    {
        new SubFolder { Folder = "Folder1", IsStandard = true },
        new SubFolder { Folder = "Folder2", IsStandard = false }
    }
};

// Display original values:
Console.WriteLine(defaultEnvCfg.ToString());

// Serialize the config to a file
var pathToEnvCfg = @"c:\public\temp\Environment.config";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(defaultEnvCfg.GetType());

using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(
    pathToEnvCfg, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, defaultEnvCfg);
}

// Prompt user to change the file
Console.Write($"Please modify the file then press [Enter] when done: {pathToEnvCfg}");
Console.ReadLine();

// Deserialize the modified file and update our object with the new settings
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(pathToEnvCfg))
{
    defaultEnvCfg = (EnvironmentConfig)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

// Display new values:
Console.WriteLine(defaultEnvCfg.ToString());

Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```